# Parameterless constructor error. (upgrade to autofac 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

In `application_start()` I have the following code.
When the Account Controller get's created I get the parameterless constructor error.
AccountController does not have a parameterless constructor. It seems that autofac is no longer configured?

Account Controller Expects the following.

`public AccountController(IFlexMembershipProvider membership, IFlexOAuthProvider openAuth)`

I am not sure why autofac is not injecting the dependences?

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<DataContext>()
    .As<IRepository>()
    .As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<FlexMembershipProvider>().As<IFlexMembershipProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<FlexMembershipProvider>().As<IFlexOAuthProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<FlexRoleProvider>().As<IFlexRoleProvider>();

builder.RegisterType<UserStorage>().As<IFlexUserStore>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<RoleStorage>().As<IFlexRoleStore>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultSecurityEncoder>().As<ISecurityEncoder>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<AspnetEnvironment>().As<IApplicationEnvironment>();
builder.RegisterType<InvestorService>().As<IInvestorService>();
builder.RegisterType<InvestmentService>().As<IInvestmentService>();
builder.RegisterType<BrokerService>().As<IBrokerService>().As<IListService<Broker>>();
builder.RegisterType<PortfolioManagerService>().As<IListService<PortfolioManager>>();

builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

var container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the assembly that contains your controllers before calling the `.Build` method:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
var container = builder.Build();
```

In this example I assumed that your application class is called `MvcApplication` and took its assembly. If your controllers are defined in a different assembly you should specify this assembly.

The [`documentation of AutoFac`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration3) has an example that you could have gone through.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this before calling builder.Build method:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource(x => !(x.IsValueType) && !(x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))));
```